# about removeObjectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

appdata.items is NSMutableArray object.

source code

```
-(void)deleteAppDataItemId:(NSInteger)identifier{
    NSLog(@"%@", [appdata.items objectAtIndex:identifier]);
    NSLog(@"%i", identifier);
    [appdata.items removeObjectAtIndex:identifier];
}
```

log

```
2009-11-08 21:53:01.683 xxx[14283:207] (
    200,
    "",
    2009-11-08 21:52:53 +0900
)
2009-11-08 21:53:01.684 xxx[14283:207] 0
2009-11-08 21:53:01.685 xxx[14283:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)'
```

What caused this error?

Comment: Can you please also log a [appdata.items count]. It looks like appdata.items is empty.

Comment: This is [appdata.items count] log.
2009-11-08 22:23:51.861 xxx[14387:207] 1

Comment: Are there any other parts of your application modifying appdata.items in another thread?

Comment: What type is stored in the array at index zero? I've not seen a description like that. The "%@" will only correctly print an object and only one that has a proper description method.

Comment: TechZen: An NSArray can only hold objects, unless you create it with CFArray and use that to put unboxed integers in it (and I think it's unlikely that the questioner has done this).

Answer (score 2):

Set the debugger to break on `objc_exception_throw`, then run your program in the debugger. When you hit the exception, look at the stack trace. Some of the frames in the stack will be in Cocoa or CF code; others will be in your code. Switch to the topmost frame that's in your code, and start examining variables. You should find the problem in short order that way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the crash happens in another array. Have you tried using a debugger?