# Objective c NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex: problem

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, nsmutablearray

I have a problem with removeObjectAtIndex: with a NSMutableArray.
I can access to object at whatever index I want, but can not remove it.

I also read this question [about removeObjectAtIndex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696339/about-removeobjectatindex) , but this didn't solve my problem.
But Diederik Hoogenboom  ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/118908/diederik-hoogenboom ) asked a question in a comment, about modifying the array in another thread, which is what I am doing, so I beleive the problem comes from there.

Any suggestions or somewhere to read from?

Thanks

Edit:
Here is my code:

```
 NSLog(@"count = %d",[_container count]);
[_container removeAllObjects];
```

And what it prints:

count = 1 
2011-08-15 16:33:21.838 asd[56809:903] *** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0)

Comment: In what way "cannot you remove it"? Does it throw an exception? Silently fail?

Comment: Yes it does. [NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (0) beyond bounds (0). And when printing the array count right before trying to remove object at index 0 , is 1.

Comment: You have no object in your array.

Comment: @Andrew: The exception says you have an empty array, yet you try to get the object at index 0.

Comment: You have tagged your question “multithreading”. Are you accessing array from different threads without locking?

Comment: @Andrew: don't do that! What's happening is probably that the other thread have emptied the array after NSLog() but before removeObjectAtIndex:

Comment: Any suggestion how to do this?

Comment: Lock a mutex around accesses or modifications of the array object if you are accessing it from multiple threads.

Comment: Read Apple's [Thread Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html) for more details about mutex locking or using @synchronized

Answer (score 2):

Given your answer to my comment, it seems like your array is just empty. As you've seen, you can't remove items from an empty array.

Edit: You've since edited your comment, so more clarification is needed. Exactly how are you determining that the length is 1 before removing an item (code please). Does the exception occur every time? Are you accessing the array from multiple threads, and if so, what is your synchronisation strategy?

Comment: Yes, it does occur every time. It seems I am accessing the array from different threads without locking as Eugene Homyakov pointed out

Comment: It's quite possible, but a little odd that the other thread beats yours *every time*. Regardless, you should always synchronise access to non-thread safe collections